# How to display decimal values in Apex Oracle using PL/SQL Code

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

[image]I'm trying to display decimal values after the user selects input from a list of values on a drop down table, then divide it with 3 to get the decimal output I want. It's working out well except when for values greater than 30 - it's not providing decimal output.

Here's my code:

```
declare

  x number(5);              
  y number(5);             
  Z float(5);       

begin
  x:= :P7_HOURS;--page item with selected value                  
  y:=3;                  
  z:=x/y;                  
  --dbms_output.put_line('Sum is '||z); 
return z;
end;
```

Comment: Where are you displaying the result? if it is a display item set it's format mask (item -> appearance -> format mask) so that it displays decimal positions (for example: 999G999G999G999G990D00). If that doesn't work try returning as : return to_char(z, '999G999G999G990D00');

Comment: @damirhuselja I am displaying the output on another page item which calculates the number of sessions based on the hours selected in the :P7_HOURS then divided by 3.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion above?

Comment: @damirhuselja I have tried the option above and it's working but the problem still persists for any values above 30. For example if the user selects 31 then after the function process, it would display 10.00 instead of 10.33.

Comment: @damirhuselja Thanks for your help, I have managed to figure out my problem. It's now able to produce the right output for the values above 30. I declared y as a float and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a display item set it's format mask (item -> appearance -> format mask) so that it displays decimal positions (for example: 999G999G999G999G990D00). If that doesn't work try returning as : return to_char(z, '999G999G999G990D00')